# Program that saves image to desktop when pressing prntscrn

Tags: windows, software-rec, images, screenshot

Is there any tool for Windows (7) that will, upon pressing the prntscrn button, save the whole screen to a .png file directly to the desktop OR to a path I can specify in the tool, instead of copying the image data to the clipboard (ideally, have the program disable this, in order to preserve data on the clipboard, but not required in the slightest)?

I have seen quite a few tools for more advanced screen capturing, but they all require me to launch the GUI and configure certain stuff every time, which I cannot possibly do in certain situations, and I'm not really after advanced options, but quicker usage, and the possibility to take multiple screenshots in a row without opening any external program just once (this included paint).

Answer (score 0):

I like [Farstone Screen Capture](http://www.faststone.org/FSCaptureDetail.htm), whilst I do not have it configured like that, it is possible.

[image]

You select the output to File/Auto Save

And you select the Auto Save options here:

[image]

It isn't free, but, it is by far the best program for screenshots that I have ever used.

(Only annoying thing is that it can't take pictures of itself as it auto hides! I had to use the snipping tool for the settings page and the output options from their site!)

Answer (score 0):

I believe SnagIt will do this, but it's not free.  Greenshot is a pretty good free screenshot utility but I'm not sure if it will automatically save to a file.

Comment: I can confirm that Snagit will do this.

Comment: Greenshot can save image, you need to set it though since it's not default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try the program called ShareX. You can print screen in any size and shape, it is like auto-cropping the picture, and will save it in a folder. It can also record mp4 and jpg other than print screen. It is also free and you can download it from the Microsoft App Store.